# Need help understanding a bad quality audio clip, help please

Tags: translation

[This](https://soundcloud.com/user-318770137/195-1?in=user-318770137/sets/t2b2) is the audio clip I'm talking about. I really appreciate your help, thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems like a single sentence with some non-standard words. What is the original source? Is there any context you can provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like "이야, 그래도 (some random sound) 그놈들이 팀 골고루 짜긴 했네." This means "Oh, at least those guys made(or divided into) teams fairly/evenly".

Comment: That "some random sound" part sounds like 우이, which is a dialect word, and we do not know whether 팀 refers to a single team or multiple teams. The OP should have provided its context.